# Python Log file count per Hour per IP

Tags: python, logging

This script that displays how many attacks occur per hour per day. I want it to also count by IP address so it will show the IP addresses that were attacked per hour, per day.

```
from itertools import groupby

#open the auth.log for reading
myAuthlog=open('auth.log', 'r') 

# Goes through the log file line by line and produces a list then looks for 'Failed password for'
myAuthlog = (line for line in myAuthlog if "Failed password for" in line) 

# Groups all the times and dates together  
for key, group in groupby(myAuthlog, key = lambda x: x[:9]): 
    month, day, hour = key[0:3], key[4:6], key[7:9]

    # prints the results out in a format to understand e.g date, time then amount of attacks
    print "On%s-%s at %s:00 There was %d attacks"%(day, month, hour, len(list(group)))
```

**The Log File looks like This**

```
Feb  3 13:34:05 j4-be02 sshd[676]: Failed password for root from 85.17.188.70 port 48495 ssh2
Feb  3 21:45:18 j4-be02 sshd[746]: Failed password for invalid user test from 62.45.87.113 port 50636 ssh2
Feb  4 08:39:46 j4-be02 sshd[1078]: Failed password for root from 1.234.51.243 port 60740 ssh2
```

**A Example outcome of the code i have is:**

```
On 3-Feb at 21:00 There was 1 attacks
On 4-Feb at 08:00 There was 15 attacks
On 4-Feb at 10:00 There was 60 attacks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby
import re
myAuthlog=open('dict.txt', 'r')
myAuthlog = (line for line in myAuthlog if "Failed password for" in line)
for key, group in groupby(myAuthlog, key = lambda x: x[:9] + re.search('from(.+?) port', x).group(1)):
    month, day, hour, ip = key[0:3], key[4:6], key[7:9] , key[10:]
    print "On%s-%s at %s:00 There was %d attacks FROM IP %s"%(day, month, hour, len(list(group)), ip)
```

Log file:

```
Feb  3 13:34:05 j4-be02 sshd[676]: Failed password for root from 85.17.188.70 port 48495 ssh2
Feb  3 21:45:18 j4-be02 sshd[746]: Failed password for invalid user test from 62.45.87.113 port 50636 ssh2
Feb  4 08:39:46 j4-be02 sshd[1078]: Failed password for root from 1.234.51.243 port 60740 ssh2
Feb  4 08:53:46 j4-be02 sshd[1078]: Failed password for root from 1.234.51.243 port 60740 ssh2
```

output:

```
On 3-Feb at 13:00 There was 1 attacks FROM IP 85.17.188.70
On 3-Feb at 21:00 There was 1 attacks FROM IP 62.45.87.113
On 4-Feb at 08:00 There was 2 attacks FROM IP 1.234.51.243
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know how to get the log lines per hour per day, use the following to count the IPs per hour per day. This is not a complete solution.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

ip_count = defaultdict(int)
with open('logfile') as data:
  for line in data:
    ip_count[re.findall(r'.*from (.*) port.*', line)[0]] += 1

for ip, count in ip_count.iteritems():
  print ip, count
```

Comment: but i want it all to print out in the same line